# No default constructor exists for class "Vector 2" when I am trying to make a constructor for another class

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a constructor for my Input class I get this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0291   no default constructor exists for class "Vector2"   RunGameEngine   C:\Users\imman\source\repos\RunGameEngine\RunGameEngine\Run\Input.cpp   5

for some reason intelisense wants me to create a default constructor for Vector2 even though I have one for it.

Input.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Window.h"

class Input
{
public:
    Input(GLFWwindow* window);
    bool isKeyPressed(float key);
    Vector2 getMousePos();
private:
    bool m_keys[348];
    Vector2 m_mousePos;
    GLFWwindow* m_window;
};
```

Input.cpp:

```
#include "Input.h"

Input::Input(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    m_window = window;
}

Vector2 Input::getMousePos()
{
    glfwGetCursorPos(m_window, &m_mousePos.x, &m_mousePos.y);
    return m_mousePos;
}

bool Input::isKeyPressed(float key)
{
    return false;
}
```

Vector.h:

```
#pragma once

struct Vector2
{
    double x, y;
    Vector2(double x, double y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};
struct Vector3
{
    double x, y, z;

    Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
};
```

Comment: The error is correct in that none of these classes has a default constructor. A default constructor is one that can be called with no arguments.

Comment: `Vector2 m_mousePos;` need to be able to default construct a `Vector2`, which does not have a default constructor; the only constructor is `Vector2(double x, double y)`, which is not a default constructor.

Comment: Add to `Input::Input(GLFWwindow* window)` this `: m_mousePos{0.0, 0.0}`

Answer (score -2):

I would do

```
Vector2 Input::getMousePos()
{
    double Pos_x;
    double Pos_y;

    glfwGetCursorPos(m_window, &Pos_x, &Pos_y);

    return Vector2(Pos_x, Pos_y);
}
```

and just skip the m_mousePos member. You don't really want to save that anyway, do you?